# how do I prevent Paper Trail from versioning on touch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

In many parts of my Rails 6 app I have `belongs_to` associations with `touch: true` which means that the `updated_at` value of the parent object gets updated when the child is updated.

The problem is that I am using the Paper Trail gem to track changes in the data, but I don't want version records for the objects when they simply have been "touched" in this way.

I've tried using the `ignore` option on the `updated_at` field like this:

```
has_paper_trail ignore: [:updated_at]
```

which causes no version to be created when I do this

```
my_object.update(updated_at: Time.current)
```

but it still creates a version when I do this

```
my_object.touch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paper Trail treats a "touch" operation separately from other updates. It can trigger versioning on any or all of these operations: create, destroy, update, touch.

Use the `on` option in order to specify a subset of operation that trigger versions that excludes 'touch'. Like this

```
has_paper_trail on: [:create, :destroy, :update]
```

In the docs this is descibed in section 2.a. ([Choosing Lifecycle Events To Monitor](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2a-choosing-lifecycle-events-to-monitor))